# How to pass parameters to servlets along with file upload using jsp and ajax?

Tags: jquery-file-upload

How to pass parameters to servlet along with file Upload using jsp servlets?

When changed to form as enctype="multipart/form-data" . Its taking only file. Its not considering parameters. If pass it shows null in servlet
And
When changed to form as enctype="multipartRequest/form-data" . Its taking only parameters. Its not considering file.

How do get parameter as well file in Servlet? Please help.